# Xamarin Studio freezes when selecting a .net solution or project

Tags: .net, xamarin

I need to modify one of the projects of an old .net solution developed with MonoDevelop and previously edited and released from within Xamarin Studio.

When I open he solution and just select any one of the projects (I mean merely click on its name) Xamarin Studio hangs: the spinning disc keeps spinning. Same result when selecting the solution name.

Maybe it is msbuild.exe that is hanging, although I never started a build. But I do see two xamarin tasks: the studio app and msbuild.exe:

```
63369 /Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/XamarinStudio
63384 /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.0/bin/mono /Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/bin/MSBuild/4.0/MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.exe
```

Using the XS for iOS targets works fine.

I detected this problem after having switched to OSX Maverick, but it might have been present without being detected before this upgrade.

Any suggestions about how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Bugs go to http://bugzilla.xamarin.com (freezing the UI is obviously a bug). Attach to it a minimal solution that reproduces the problem.